# universal_cookie__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.remove is not a function

Tags: cookies, universal

whenever am i trying to remove cookie its show me this error.

```
TypeError: universal_cookie__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.remove is not a function
```

this is my code

```
 Logout = () =>{
    var user = Cookies.get('shailuKiCookie');
    // console.log(user);
    if(user){
      Cookies.remove("shailuKiCookie");
      // alert("logout successfully");
      window.location.reload(false);
    }else{
      window.location.reload(false);
    }
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2vnr.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
function set_cookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name +'='+ value +'; Path=/;';
}
function delete_cookie(name) {
  document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

You don't have to specify a cookie value when you delete a cookie.

Just set the expires parameter to a past date:

note : HttpOnly cookies cannot be deleted with JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: can u help me with reactjs

Answer (score 0):

you should create a Cookies object.

```
const cookies = new Cookies()
cookies.remove('cookie name')
```